# Android - attaching multiple files in email intent crashes Gmail

Tags: android, crash, gmail, email-attachments

I try to attach multiple files in an E-mail intent this way (which i saw in an accepted answer in stackoverflow):

```
String[] attachments;<--contains all the filenames i want to attach;
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for (String file : attachments){
    if(!file.equals("")){
        Log.w("-"+file +"-","attached");
        File fileIn = new File(file);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
        uris.add(u);
    }
}
//check that uri list is correct
for(Uri uri1:uris){
    Log.w(uri1.toString(),"uri list");
}

intMail.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

This code causes Gmail client to crash and the logcat says as a warning:

```
Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected Parcelable but value was a java.util.ArrayList.The default value <null> was returned.
```

After that Gmal crashes and logcat says

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10355): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I don't get what i am doing wrong....Any useful advice/input?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Intent.ACTION_SEND, try to use Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE when you create intMail.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677513/unable-to-attach-multiple-files-to-an-email-in-android)

Comment: that is only available in newer API versions. My app is ment for all versions from 8 and up

Comment: `emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");` was also needed in my case, when I attached multiple images